# Eclipse + Egit - adding a new Java project to a remote repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I have a Java project in Eclipse that I maintain using a local git repository (The repository has only that one project).

I've been asked to push this project to a remote git repository. This repository already has other projects in it (and apparently the plan is to maintain all my team's projects in this repository).

How would I go about doing this using Eclipse and Egit? (Alternatively, I wouldn't mind doing this on the command line as well).

When I tried the "normal" procedure for pushing a project using Egit (Right-click project -> Team -> Remote -> Push) I get an error "master: master [rejected - non-fast-forward].

Comment: does the remote repository handle the different projects in branches or in subfolders in the msater branch?

Comment: @zolex: I guess we can choose to do that either way. Is there a preferred method?

Comment: the preferred method is to have only one project in one repository, but it would be more clean to have a branch for each project if more than one project must be in the same repository. see my answer on how to add a branch to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following and replace the <tags> with your data

```
git clone <git_url> <foldername>
cd <foldername>
git checkout -b <new_project_name>
<copy all your files to the folder>
git push origin <new_project_name>
```

Comment: That worked, and yes it makes more sense to track each project as a branch. Thanks!

Comment: This is git--not egit, as the title requested.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing a git pull to sync up with the remote repository, then you should be able to push to it. The non-fast-forward most likely means you have an old copy checked out.

Comment: I don't have an old copy checked out anywhere. I will try checking out a copy and doing a git pull and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried, and it didn't make any difference. I still get the same error. Do you have any other suggestions? Am I doing something horribly wrong?